# Taking multiple user entries Without using arrays java

Tags: java, string

I've just started a intro to programming class and I'm having serious trouble with this. I basically have to take a int, double, boolean, char and string from a user the amount of times they specify and compare them. I'm having trouble actually taking the inputs.

The Problem is:

Modify the program so that, instead of comparing only two sets (records) of values (e.g. first integer vs. second integer, first boolean vs.
second boolean, etc.), the program compares an arbitrary number of records. Your code must not use arrays at this stage and it should still
achieve this behavior using only two variables for each data type.

To get the user data I have tried this :

```
    int numberUsers = Integer.parseInt(gt.getInputString("How many people are we comparing?"));
    
    int dataPoints = 0;
    while (dataPoints <= numberUsers) {

        String rawInput = gt.getInputString("For person" + dataPoints
                + ", enter in the following format: Height,Hourly Rate,Satisfied with course,Last exam grade,name.");
        String[] enteredData = rawInput.split(",");
        int userHeight = Integer.parseInt(enteredData[0]);
        double hourRate = Double.parseDouble(enteredData[1]);
        boolean satisfiedCourse = Boolean.parseBoolean(enteredData[2]);
        char userGrade = enteredData[3].charAt(0);
        String userName = enteredData[4];
        dataPoints++;
```

the problem I'm having is to start a new string input for users after the first is taken. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a ```hasNextLine()``` method, i think this can help, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-hasnextline-method-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: I'm not getting what you are trying to achieve, do you want to compare two Users with their height, grade, name etc? Or set of users (more than 2) and for each category who is highest??

Comment: Include the code for comparison.

Comment: What is `gt.getInputString`?

Answer (score 1):

In case the output of the program is supposed to be the max or min value for each data type, it is possible to do that with 2 variables for each type.
For instance, here's what I would do to find the max height and the max hour rate:

```
int maxUserHeight = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
double maxHourRate = Double.MIN_VALUE;
int dataPoints = 0;
while (dataPoints <= numberUsers) {
    String rawInput = gt.getInputString("For person" + dataPoints
            + ", enter in the following format: Height,Hourly Rate,Satisfied with course,Last exam grade,name.");
    String[] enteredData = rawInput.split(",");

    int userHeight = Integer.parseInt(enteredData[0]);
    if (userHeight > maxUserHeight)
        maxUserHeight = userHeight;

    double hourRate = Double.parseDouble(enteredData[1]);
    if (hourRate > maxHourRate)
        maxHourRate = hourRate;

    boolean satisfiedCourse = Boolean.parseBoolean(enteredData[2]);
    char userGrade = enteredData[3].charAt(0);
    String userName = enteredData[4];
    dataPoints++;
}
```